# doctrine SQLFilter disable auto quoting for IN query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i create filter  Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

here is query modification

Application::CRM_APP_IDS is 1,2,5

```
 $app_ids = $this->getParameter(Application::CRM_APP_IDS);

 return "{$targetTableAlias}.application_id IN ($app_ids)";
```

i get quoted query IN ('1,2,5')

how i can use IN in sqlFilter

I do this in - Doctrine filter - in this place there is no QueryBuilder avaible - http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html

update 1

for now i use loop and where app= or app= or app= but maybe anyone know better way.

Answer (score -1):

That would be:

```
$expr = new Expr\Func($x . ' IN', (array) $y);
```

as found in [`doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php:443`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php#L443)

We use it by adding it to the QueryBuilder:

```
$builder->andWhere($expr);
```

Comment: i update doc - in doctrine filter querybuilder is not avaible

Comment: The QueryBuilder was just an example about how to add the expression. You can also add it in your example about the `SQLFilter`.

Comment: No i cant add querybuilder in sqlFilter - its not service

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, I meant to say that this has nothing to do with the `QueryBuilder` at all, but that you can also use it at your own `SQLFilter` if you'd like.

Comment: can you show my example off SqlFilter with custom SqlFilter ? i create SqlFIlter and dont have idea how to use IN in where - its auto quoted.

Comment: Whether you use a `SQLFilter` or `QueryBuilder`, you should use the expression as above to create the `IN` expression. So the filter should return your expression via `addFilterConstraint`.